# Edit python global variable defined in different file

Tags: python, global-variables

I am using Python 2.7. I want to store a variable so that I can run a script without defining the variable in that script. I think global variables are the way to do this although I am open to correction.

I have defined a global variable in `file1.py`:

```
def init():
    global tvseries
    tvseries = ['Murder I Wrote','Top Gear']
```

In another file, `file2.py`, I can call this variable:

```
import file1
file1.init()
print file1.tvseries[0]
```

If I edit the value of file1.tvseries (`file1.tvseries[0] = 'The Bill'`) in file2.py this is not stored. How can I edit the value of file1.tvseries in file2.py so that this edit is retained?

**EDIT: Provide answer**

Using `pickle`:

```
import  pickle

try:
    tvseries = pickle.load(open("save.p","rb"))
except:
    tvseries = ['Murder I Wrote','Top Gear']

print tvseries
tvseries[0] = 'The Bill'
print tvseries
pickle.dump(tvseries,open("save.p", "wb"))
```

Using `json`:

```
import json

try:
    tvseries = json.load(open("save.json"))
    tvseries = [s.encode('utf-8') for s in tvseries]
except:
    tvseries = ['Murder I Wrote','Top Gear']

print tvseries
tvseries[0] = str('The Bill')
print tvseries
json.dump(tvseries,open("save.json", "w"))
```

Both these files return `['Murder I Wrote','Top Gear']['The Bill','Top Gear']` when run the first time and `['The Bill','Top Gear']['The Bill','Top Gear']` when run the second time.

Comment: where do u make the edit in file 1 or 2

Comment: @SuJaY I make the edit in `file2.py`.

Comment: So you want the change made in `file2.py` to actually change the script `file1.py`? Why don't you store the *"global variable"* in a text file (e.g. using JSON or `pickle`) instead? What's the point in it being defined in a Python file?

Comment: I think you are confusing globals with *persistence*; storing values for later reloading. Python source code doesn't change when you change the global, next time Python starts, the source code will once again set `tvseries[0]` to `'Murder I Wrote'`. Look at the `pickle` or `marshall` or even `json` modules instead; save the data in a separate file and re-save it each time the data changes.

Comment: If you are new to Python, dont use two separate files for something that apparently can be done in one file.

Comment: @jonrsharpe @Martijn Pieters @HeinzKurt From the comments I think I should use `pickle` or `json`. I don't know what these are, can you show or link and example?

Comment: ...have you tried searching for them, at all?

Comment: you will need import pickle, pickle.load and pickle.dump
Thats all. And please do not use two python files. Still a simple text file for storage might be easier to use for you, if you are new to Python

Comment: To clarify do you want changes made to the variable `tvseries` to be saved to a file so that they are present the next time you run the program?

Comment: @nettux443 Yes, I would like the changes to saved so they are present when the file is run again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
Create a file called **tvseries** with these contents:

```
Murder I Wrote
Top Gear
```

**file1.py**:

```
with open("tvseries", "r") as f:
    tvseries = map(str.strip, f.readlines())

def save(tvseries):
    with open("tvseries", "w") as f:
        f.write("\n".join(tvseries))
```

**file2.py**:

```
import file1

print file1.tvseries[0]
file1.tvseries.append("Dr Who")
file1.save(file1.tvseries)
```

I've moved the contents of your `init` method out to module level since I don't see any need for it to exist. When you `import file1` any code at the module level will be automatically run - eliminating the need for you to manually run `file1.init()`. I've also changed the code to populate the contents of `tvseries` by reading from a simple text file called **tvseries** containing a list of tv series and added a `save` method in **file1.py** which will write the contents of it's argument to the file **tvseries**.